# Optimized RPG inventory parsing using OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to develop an OpenCV-based [Path of Exile](http://pathofexile.com) inventory parser. The inventory looks like [this, with items left and right.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08n8R.png) The round things on items are called "sockets", are randomized, but they can be hidden.

There are two options for this:

- When you hover an item in game, and press `CTRL-C`, a description of the item is copied to your clipboard. A solution would be to do this on every single inventory cell, to re-create the whole inventory, bit per bit. There is an issue with this, however: the "item copy" action is probably logged somewhere, and having `12 * 5 = 60` actions like this in under 2 seconds would definitely look fishy on GGG's (the devs) end.
- Using image-recognition software to decompose the inventory like a human being would. There are several methods with this, and I'm struggling to find the most effective.

---

## Method 1: Sprite detection

This is the "obvious" method. Store the sprite of every single item in the game (I think there must be around 900-ish sprites for all the bases and unique items, so probably around 250 sprites if we exclude the unique items), and perform sprite detection for each of them, on the whole inventory. This is without a doubt extremely overkill. And it requires tons of storage. Discarded.

## Method 2: Reverse sprite detection

For every single sprite in the game, calculate an associated md5, and store it in a file. Using OpenCV, cut the inventory's items one by one, calculate their md5, and match against the file to detect which item it is. It's probably faster this way, but still needs a ton of processing power.

## Method 3: Same than #2 but smarter

Use OpenCV to cut the items one by one, and based on their size, optimize the search (2x2 item means that it's either a helmet, boots, gloves, or a shield. 2x1 item is always a belt. 1x1 is always a ring/amulet, and so on).

---

Is there another method that I'm forgetting? All of these look like they need both heavy processing, code, and before-hand work from me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If Method 2 is actually practical (your item detector can reliably extract pixel-perfect sprites), it's very likely to be the best method bar none, and it won't be as computationally heavy as you make it out to be. For one, MD5 digests are 16 bytes long only, and a pixel is only 3 bytes for 8-bit RGB; Hashing a sprite should take nano- or micro-seconds. If you've put the name of every item in a hash table keyed by the MD5 of its sprite beforehand, you'll be done in no time with minimal CPU and memory use.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for confirming @IwillnotexistIdonotexist